# Popup window working out the height

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a problem where I am position a popup `<div>` in the center of the window using:

```
var popup = $("#popup"), popupWidth = popup.css("width").replace("px",""), popupHeight = popup.css("height").replace("px","");
    var xPosition = ($(window).width() - popupWidth) / 2;
    var yPosition = (($(window).height() - popupHeight) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop();

    if (yPosition <= 0){
        yPosition = '0'; 
    } else if(yPosition <= $(window).scrollTop()){
        yPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
    } else {
        yPosition = yPosition - 68; //minus top shaddow height
    }           

    if (xPosition >= $('body').offset().left) {
        xPosition = xPosition;
    } else {
        xPosition = '0';
    }

    $(popup).css({
        'top': yPosition + 'px',
        'left': xPosition + 'px',
        'display' : 'block',
        'height' : 'auto'
    }).addClass("popup-open");
```

The problem I had was that on first load the height of the popup was being returned as 0 because it is hidden until after the position above has been worked out. To resolve this I set a default height via CSS and then once the popup has been displayed I overwrite this to auto.

The problem now is that if the popup has been closed and re-opened the height is auto. Is there a way to find the CSS height:value in the stylesheet not the inline height:auto

**Updated Code**
Following Nicola answer here is the fixed code:

```
var popup = $("#popup"), popupWidth = popup.css("width").replace("px",""), popupHeight = popup.css("height").replace("px","");

// Save/Get original height
if(popupHeight == "auto"){
    popupHeight = popup.data('origHeight');
} else {
    popup.data('origHeight', popupHeight);
}

var xPosition = ($(window).width() - popupWidth) / 2;
var yPosition = (($(window).height() - popupHeight) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you save the original values in a variable?

```
var popup = $("#popup"), popupWidth = popup.css("width").replace("px",""), popupHeight = popup.css("height").replace("px","");

var originalHeight = popupHeight;
var originalWidth = popupWidth;
```

When you reopen the pop up you use the original values instead of the actual values

Or you could use use [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data) to store it and retrieve it

```
 $('#popup').data('origHeight', popupHeight);
 //the use  $('#popup').data('origHeight') to retrieve it
```